# x86-64 Assembly "cmovge" to C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, decompiling

While I shouldn't list out the entire 4 line sample I'm given, (since this is a homework question) I'm confused how this should be read and translated into C.

`cmovge  %edi, %eax`

What I understand so far is that the instruction is a conditional move for when the result is >=. It's comparing the first parameter of a function `%edi` to the integer register `%eax` (which was assigned the other parameter value `%esi` in the previous line of assembly code). However, I don't understand its result.

My problem is interpreting the optimized code. It doesn't manipulate the stack, and I'm not sure how to write this in C (or at least the `gcc` switch I could even use to generate the same result when compiling).

Could someone please give a few small examples of how the `cmovge` instruction might translate into C code? If it doesn't make sense as its own line of code, feel free to make something up with it.

This is in x86-64 assembly through a virtualized Linux operating system (CentOS 7).

Comment: Have you read the insn ref manual: HTML extract here: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMOVcc.html.  More links in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm probably giving you the whole solution here:

`int
doit(int a, int b) {
    return a >= b ? a : b;
}`

With `gcc -O3 -masm=intel` becomes:

```
doit:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    cmp edi, esi
    mov eax, esi
    cmovge  eax, edi
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, thank you! And thanks for the switch `-O3`, that's a big help!

Comment: `a >= b ? b : a;`?

Comment: @Miharu461 (and Björn): don't forget that flags can come from anything.  The cmov part is really just the `eax = greater ? edi : eax` part, where `bool greater` could be set by anything, not necessarily involving `a` or `b`.  So `a = x>=y : b : a` can still compile to a cmovge.